# Find dependency in another sheet (Libre Office Calc 7.6.0.3)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, libreoffice-calc

If a cell is mentioned somewhere within a sheet, like an equation, LO Calc takes me to that reference by selecting the cell and pressing `Shift+F5` by showing an arrow. This however fails when the reference is in another sheet within the same file. Here, I only get the "dead-end" blue square above the selected cell.

[Two](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/trace-dependents-precedents-when-in-another-sheet/150) [posts](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/trace-dependecies-that-are-in-another-worksheet/70616) on the LO forum show that this can apparently be done by pressing `Ctrl+]`. However, I can't find any mentions of this shortcut in the [docs](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/shared/guide/keyboard.html?&DbPAR=CALC&System=WIN) nor [tutorials](https://www.maketecheasier.com/cheatsheet/libreoffice-calc-keyboard-shortcuts/). Additionally, I am confused by this shortcut, as my Swiss keyboard requires me to hit `AltGr`, because the square brackets are the 3rd option of two keys each. This means that the shortcut may not work for me, because I'm using it wrong. Having this feature would greatly improve the ability to understand foreign spreadsheets and to remove deprecated unused values, which is my goal.

**How can I get a dependency for a reference in another sheet?**

Comment: Please try in the [**Tools - Customize - Keyboard tab**](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/shared/01/06140200.html) to find the **Mark Precedents** and **Mark Dependents** functions in the Options category and assign keyboard shortcuts for them that will be convenient for you. I'm not promising that the functions will always work correctly, but at least you'll feel more comfortable calling them.

Comment: @JohnSUN thank you for the input, I changed "mark dependents" to `Ctrl+,` and "mark precedents" to `Ctrl+.`. Weirdly, going from the reference back to the source with `Ctrl+.` works, but not the other way around. Can you confirm this?

Comment: Perhaps [**this discussion**](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/selection-changed-event/91418/5?u=johnsun) will help you find an acceptable workaround

Comment: As I understand, that would require me having clicked the dependent cell before, which I can't. The sheet's contents are up to 2000 rows long and I need to find the cells within a column which are not referenced anywhere, meaning that every entry of that column that does not highlight another cell with **Mark Dependents** is a target that can be deleted.

Comment: Maybe a possible workaround would be if I could search for **expressions** (e.g. `=$Sheet3.B2`) instead of the **contents** (e.g. `A_STRING_DEFINED_IN_SHEET3_B2`) of the cell with that expression. @JohnSUN is there a way to do that?

Comment: A possible macro version that can perform such a task [**was published here**](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/remove-trace-arrows-trace-arrow-toggle/51829/6?u=johnsun)